# LDAP Query in c# using DirectorySearcher does not return anything

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I run the following LDAP query using DirectorySearcher which is bound to the root of the AD:

```
(&(|(objectClass=container)(objectClass=organizationalUnit))(!(distinguishedName=OU=)(*&^%\\\#@$!\\\#$%^,OU=xyxy.yxyx,OU=yyyy,OU=tttt,DC=base,DC=local)))
```

But, it does not return any OUs. When i run the same query with an other OU like below, i get all the other OUs in AD:

```
(&(|(objectClass=container)(objectClass=organizationalUnit))(!(distinguishedName=OU=SOMEOU,OU=xyxy.yxyx,OU=yyyy,OU=tttt,DC=base,DC=local)))
```

Basically, I am trying to run a query for all the OUs which exclude some specific OUs.  I guess it has something to do with the special character in the OU name.

Comment: What is the name of the OU that you want to exclude? `*&^%\\\#@$!\\\#$%^,OU=xyxy.yxyx,OU=yyyy,OU=tttt,DC=base,DC=local`?

Comment: Name of the OU i am using is:  )(*&^%\#@$!\#$%^and that is under OU tttt which is under OU yyyy and the whole thing is under the domain base.local.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the the name of the OU is `)(*&^%\#@$!\#$%^` as it appears in active directory users and computers. If you open the attribute editor you would find the following value for the distinguishedName attribute: `OU=)(*&^%\\\#@$!\\\#$%^,OU=....` (notice that here the number of backslashes doubled and an extra backslash is added).

Based on this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `(`, `)`, `*`, and `\` (and others) need to be escaped.

- * becomes \2a
- ( becomes \28
- ) becomes \29
- \ becomes \5c

So your OU name in the LDAP filter should become `OU=\29\28\2a&^%\5c\5c\5c#@$!\5c\5c\5c#$%^,OU=....`

Please note that you need to escape the `\` characters here or use `@` in C# to create a verbatim string like this:

```
string dn = @"OU=\29\28\2a&^%\5c\5c\5c#@$!\5c\5c\5c#$%^,OU=...
```

Comment: as i mentioned in the comment in the question, the OU name as it appears under Active Directory is  )(*&^%\#@$!\#$%^  see this under attribute editor: )(*&^%\\\#@$!\\\#$%^  (Sorry, i don't know how to start a new line in the comment).

Comment: Yes you are right. The way the query was forward was wrong. But i would expect the query to fail and my DirectorySearcher to throw an exception. Instead it returned an empty result.